# $setValidity not updating $valid flag in real-time

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I'm using a custom form input validator implemented using a directive.  In the directive, the validation event is bound to the input's blur event. So on blur, it sets the validity of the model using $setValidity.  However, the $valid state is not updated until the model's value is modified again.  In other words, the $valid state always lags one state behind.

More specifically, I'm using the Angular Stripe helper library made available by backlift.com.  Here's the code block I'm referring to: [Line 613 here.](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments/blob/master/lib/angular-payments.js#L613)

On view, I have div blocks as such:

```
<div class="field-box error" ng-show="myForm.field.$dirty && myForm.field.$invalid">
    <div class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> Some friendly message</div>
</div>
```

Any idea why $valid/$invalid properties are not updated as soon as the on-blur event is executed? FYI, the _validate method does its job correctly and $setValidity() is called with the correct values when expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to user "scope.$digest" after the value get updated in your directive?

Comment: @geniuscarrier: scope.$digest did the trick.  Why don't you post an answer so I can accept it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. This article probably will help you understand deeply: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scope.$digest` will solve your problem. Whenever you integrate a non-Angular plugin in directive, make sure to do scope.$digest to keep scope updated.